# After changes in less file setup:static-content:deploy is compulsory

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

Most of time spend on setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy.
Is it compulsory to run both command after changes on less file?
I have used Default lUMA theme.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run setup:upgrade:command if the changes you have made only are in less files.

However you have to run setup:static-content:deploy to see less files changes, also you can deploy static content from admin as well ( Magento 2 CE ):

System->Cache Management -> Flush static files ( bottom of page ).

Comment: You mean After changes any less file, Only I need to run php bin/magento cache:flush  ?

Comment: No, in admin go to cache management section there will be a button " Flush Static Files" , it will redeploy static files

Comment: It Breaks  css load.  When I check pub/static folder Fronted folder is not exists. Then Again I need to fire all deploy command.

Comment: did you check if there is any permission issue ? are you deploying static content forcefully ? using command -f

Comment: I am in windows. there are no any permission issue. I use System->Cache Management -> Flush static files ( bottom of page ). so no need to make any command if we are from admin GUI side.

Comment: Yes that is correct, from UI it is not needed, and permission is of course Linux issue did you check if there is any issue in your theme ext_all.css file some time it happens due to issue in your css typo.

Comment: @NaveedAsim for a while I thought you meant there may be differences between running Flush from command or from Admin UI? So does php bin/magento cache:flush equals Flush from Admin UI Cache Management?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps:

1.Install Grunt Cli tool by runnig this command npm install -g grunt-cli

2.cd your_Magento_instance_directory

3.Rename package.json.sample to package.json and Gruntfile.js.sample to Gruntfile.js

4.run npm install

5.Create you own theme (ex:Sample/Mytheme) I guess it's already done ;)

6.Create a less file like that  app/design/frontend/Sample/Mytheme/web/css/source/_theme.less and add this code

```
body{
  background-color:red;
}
```

7.add the below code to the file dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

```
mytheme>: {
area: 'frontend',
name: 'Sample/Mytheme',
locale: 'en_US',
files: [
'css/styles-m',
'css/styles-l'
],
dsl: 'less'
}
```

8. grunt clean
9. grunt exec:mytheme
10. grunt less:mytheme
11. Afterwards, reload the frontend page , your background color should be changed to red.

If you run grunt watch and you change your less file Grunt will automatically update all necessary files .

I hope my answer was clear. Good luck and happy coding !!!

Comment: Dear friends. In Ubuntu command works fast. I am using Windows and command processes slow. So let me know if you have any solution for windows.